# Decrypt multiple drives with a single password? (LUKS+LVM)

Tags: partitioning, encryption, lvm, luks

Specifically to be able to rearrange the LUKS volumes without touching physical partitions.

(I'm willing to start from scratch)

Background: Currently I have LVM on top of LUKS. A password unlocks root volume, which contains the encryption keys for the other drives. Unfortunately, as far as I know the only way to move disk space elsewhere into the root volume is to resize physical partitions, which is a pain.

Comment: I'm not sure If I'll create a proper answer, but the solution seems to be the classic "store keys on the root drive which unlock other partitions" + having the root logical volume in the same volume group as all the others.  It causes some warnings but seems to work.

Comment: Resizing physical partitions is not that bad. KDE Partition Manager 3.0 can easily do this even online without using Live CD.

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas But resizing the LUKS areas is a pain. It's like resizing real partitions used to be. You have to muck about with raw sector counts, add the header size, etc. Feels like i'm back in MS-DOS again.

Comment: that's why use GUI, don't do it by hand.

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas Yes, according to google you can now resize LUKS in KDE Partition Manager. But wow, when did that happen? Tyvm.

Comment: This happened in spring of 2016 or so. Calamares installer maintainer Teo Mrnjavac and I added required support and then released KPM 2.1. In fact after Google Summer of Code now KPM 3.0 is release with LVM support as well.